# Is there any way wherein one can include Google Cloud Endpoint to an existing Google App Project

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

My question here is to expose my browser APIs to the world without rewriting it for other devices. For this I am using Google Cloud Endpoints.

While working around it and goind through the documentation I created a sample spring boot application project on Google Cloud Platform. Deployed the project using App Engine. But I need some information about configuring the Google Cloud Endpoint to the existing project since I have novice experience in Google Cloud Platform.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

Used the above link to configure to the Spring Application to App Engine.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-endpoints-appengine/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0

The above link uses the github repository to demostrate the Google Cloud Endpoint.

Need help on how can I configure the same on my existing project running in Google App Engine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently GCP Endpoints are GA for GCP App Engine Flex.

Having said this, perhaps you just need to **add GCP Endpoints** layer (via Cloud Run and OpenAPI/Swagger) **on top of your existing GAE app** (and/or apps), by following the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#endpoints_configure) here.

There is an example for Java app on GAE Flex as well.

Comment: Yes Andrei. I included it. But I somewhat feel it a bit vague about it because I was able to access my service in other devices even without the endpoints being  configured.

Comment: Check IAP (Identity-Aware Proxy) via App Engine Settings.

Comment: Checked it. But with this I am granted access to url with signing but what about the accessibility at the device level.

Comment: Hi Andrei can you please look into the picture attached to the main question. Even though I access my endpoint the request count is still zero. Am I missing something or did I do something wrong. Can you please let me know. Thank you so much.

Comment: What about tracing? What do you see in https://console.cloud.google.com/traces/traces ?

Comment: Yes I see all the request incoming there.